# Does the limit of `canOpenURL` really work?

Tags: ios, objective-c, foundation

The Document says

> If your app is linked against an earlier version of iOS but is running
> in iOS 9.0 or later, you can call this method up to 50 times. After
> reaching that limit, subsequent calls always return NO. If the user
> reinstalls or upgrades the app, iOS resets the limit.

I collected thousands of url schemes in some way. The purpose is to collect the apps installed on my user's iPhone.

I know it violates Apple's privacy policy but this is not the scope of this issue.

But in my tests, I did collect more than 50 apps which means this method can be called much more than 50 times. considering that my url scheme list is very large.

So does this rule really works?Or a bug of Apple?

[image: part of the info.plist]

Comment: Are you going to list thousands of URL schemes in your Info.plist?

Comment: There is an if statement *If your app is linked against an earlier version of iOS* **but** is running in iOS 9.0 or later. The way I understand this is that you developed it app for let's say iOS 8 but your app runs on iOS 9 or later in some devices, then that limit kicks in. This is nothing but my opinion

Comment: @rmaddy ok i edit the issue,and this number will grow bigger.

Comment: You have to use Xcode 10.2 or later which means a Base SDK of iOS 12 or later. So that info seems irrelevant. You have to whitelist any URL scheme you wish to use with `canOpenURL`.

Comment: @rmaddy actually this is the whitelist

Comment: I'm saying the documentation you quote is irrelevant. Your bigger worry is Apple rejecting your app for having too many entries under LSApplicationQueriesSchemes. Their whole goal is to prevent apps like yours being in the App Store.

Comment: Yes,i am worrying this.But I can't find Apple's case of punishment for such events.Also,I don't know which number is safe.

Comment: @HensonFang Apple won't 'punish' you, they simply won't put your app in the App Store.

Comment: May be it's working unlimited with developer provisioning profile.

Comment: Yes the 50 limit does apply, I've observed it first hand.